# ar_kinect crashes after throwing 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: ros, ar-pose, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

ar_kinect keeps throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' after running for a few seconds on my computer (see code below for a typical run). I'm using it to detect and track the pose of 6 different visual tags (more specifically, patterns 8,9,18,20,40, and 95). Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
user@machine:~/ROS/stacks/albany_vision/ar_kinect$ rosrun ar_kinect ar_kinect
[ INFO] [1333136036.628410336]:     Publish transforms: 1
[ INFO] [1333136036.629539353]:     Publish visual markers: 1
[ INFO] [1333136036.630507217]:     Threshold: 100
[ INFO] [1333136036.631441118]: Marker Pattern Filename: /home/user/ROS/stacks/albany_vision/ar_kinect/data/objects_kinect
[ INFO] [1333136036.632474078]: Marker Data Directory: /home/user/ROS/stacks/albany_vision/ar_kinect
[ INFO] [1333136040.534424133]: *** Camera Parameter ***
--------------------------------------
SIZE = 640, 480
Distortion factor = 320.000000 240.000000 0.000000 1.000000
-1.91486 -1.90712 -0.00000 0.00000 
-0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 -0.00000 
0.00000 -0.00000 -0.00000 -0.00000 
--------------------------------------
[ INFO] [1333136040.534641373]: Opening Data File /home/user/ROS/stacks/albany_vision/ar_kinect/data/objects_kinect
[ INFO] [1333136040.535601997]: About to load 6 Models
[ INFO] [1333136040.535819964]: Read in No.1
[ INFO] [1333136040.539944225]: Read in No.2
[ INFO] [1333136040.540854799]: Read in No.3
[ INFO] [1333136040.541632103]: Read in No.4
[ INFO] [1333136040.544074185]: Read in No.5
[ INFO] [1333136040.545178050]: Read in No.6
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30887/ar_kinect-crashes-after-throwing-%27std::out_of_range%27/) by [Pedro Santana](https://answers.ros.org/users/2090/pedro-santana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would appear that your "marker_data_directory" is wrong -- it most likely needs to point at the ar_pose directory (as we did not copy all that data into ar_kinect). You probably want to use a launch file to set the parameters (see the examples in the launch directory of ar_kinect).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0